# Как расположить несколько элементов в ряд android?

Tags: android, textview, android-button, android-linearlayout

У меня в приложении нужно разместить несколько элементов в ряд, то есть у нас слева направо должны быть размещены кнопка textview и опять кнопка, я это запихнул в отдельный linearlayout и пытаюсь все марджинами подогнать, на превью в студии все выглядит хорошо, но когда запускаю на емуляторе то самая крайняя кнопка справа растягивается по горизонтали. У меня есть такой код для виджетов:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_do_not_disturb_on_black_24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/min"/>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/num"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/add" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Может у меня есть где-то ошибка в разметке, или проблема в чем-то другом. Если кто знает где я ошибся буду благодарен если покажите на ошибку.

Comment: Используйте ConstraintLayout, он позволяет располагать элементы в зависимости друг от друга https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: непонятно, чего вы хотите добиться и что работает не так. "пытаюсь все марджинами подогнать" - вообще неясно как и зачем) Скрин бы. Навскидку: сделайте не `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, а `="0dp"` (так в любом случае правильно). Может быть дело в `@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp`.

Comment: та у меня уже через constraintlayout вроде получилось, спасибо))